# Ctrl + Shift + T Is not working

Tags: texturing

When I click <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> the window pops up for me to select the materials but when ever I click principled textured setup nothing pops up in the nodes. Note, I do have node wrangler on.

Edit: So everyone is telling me to provide more information. Whenever I go into the file viewer to add the materials I select over them:
[image]

And then after I click the "Principled textured setup" button at the bottom right. However, when I do so no nodes pop up on the left side. Also note, no error messages pop up either.

Comment: You haven't provided enough information for us to guess what's going on at the moment. Can you describe the exact sequence of events that you're using which is failing, possibly including images of your node tree.

Comment: @ John Eason
If an active shader editor window open, and try pressing Ctrl + T instead of Ctrl + Shift + T for the Principled Texture Setup. Also, double-check that Node Wrangler is enabled and functioning correctly.

Comment: What do you mean, when you click _Principled Texture Setup_ nothing pops up? Have you chosen image files before clicking _Principled Texture Setup_? Have you (before pressing `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `T`) selected a _Principled BSDF_ in the node tree to which the textures can be connected?

Comment: @RileyM That's incorrect! Ctrl-T adds a Texture Coordinate, Image Texture and Mapping Node to the Principled BDSF node. It is **not* used to to add the Principled texture setup which, as I said earlier, is Ctrl-Shift-T. Also those hotkeys would do nothing if the Node Wrangler addon wasn't enabled.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I guess he's mentioning the File View dialogue, its validation button is named "Principled Texture Setup" when opened from `Ctrl` `Shift` `T`.

Comment: @L0Lock I know, my question was what exactly is happening... you can click that button without having selected anything and this might result in nothing showing up in the nodetree. I guess for a similar reason John was asking in the first comment for "the exact sequence of events". I therefore also specified in my question if image files are chosen before clicking the button or if a _Principled BSDF_ was selected before opening the dialogue... and me mentioning "clicking _Principled Texture Setup_" obviously indicates I know the button is named like that.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in [Node Wrangler — Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/4.0/addons/node/node_wrangler.html?utm_source=blender-4.0.1#add-principled-texture-setup)

> Add a principled texture setup from the selected texture files. Select a Principled BSDF node, select *Add Principled Setup* from the quick access menu (or press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), and select texture files. It automates the process of adding Image Texture nodes, loading images, selecting the appropriate Color Space, and connecting their outputs to the Principled BSDF node.
>
> It detects the type of textures by looking at their file names. You can edit the tags used for this matching process in the add-on preferences.

If you select no textures, or if they file names aren't recognizable for the addon to know their individual functions, validating the file dialogue will result in nothing but an info dialog:

[image]

If your textures aren't named with their functions as suffixes, then most likely they are not made to be used as PBR textures to begin with.

Further reading:

- Guide to understand PBR and textures:
  [ArtStation - Everything About PBR Textures And A Little More - PART
  1](https://www.artstation.com/blogs/luismesquita/PwEm/everything-about-pbr-textures-and-a-little-more-part-1)
- An example of commonly used PBR textures suffixes:
  [Materials and Textures – Sketchfab Help Center](https://help.sketchfab.com/hc/en-us/articles/202600873-Materials-and-Textures#textures-auto-pbr)

Answer (score 0):

In order to make this function to work, you have to have the **Node wrangler addon** activated and the Principled BSDF Node selected, then press  <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

Comment: as a comment on this. You also have to have the textures with the correct names so Node wrangler can use them correctly (roughness_"texturename", Height_"texturename" and so)